# Problems with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to mysql and I am trying to install a simple script on a friend's website. It asks me for this:

```
Database Server Host
Database Server Port
Admin Username
Admin Password
Database Name
Database Login
Database Password
Database Password Confirm
```

and I gave it this info:

```
Database Server Host: localhost
Database Server Port: 3306
Admin Username: intap_school
Admin Password: test123
Database Name: intap_sch
Database Login: ???
Database Password: ????
Database Password Confirm: ????
```

I have also created a database called "intap_sch" and I putted a user called "intap_school" on it with all privileges.

Comment: Firstly, the admin password is very, very weak. Make a very complex password ( store a copy somewhere, like in a password manager ). Similarly, create the login name and password - again complex and keep them safe. Remove the link to the actual `live site` - especially given that you have credentials here on display

Comment: ikr this is a test site and a test database :P

Comment: Although that won't help much seeing as SO retains a history. So change the password, and don't tell us it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin login and database login is the same usually (or admin is `root`), so try this:

```
Admin Username: intap_school

Admin Password: test123

Database Name: intap_sch

Database Login: intap_school

Database Password: test123

Database Password Confirm: test123
```